# Xamarin android - Cannot start a service in a separate Xamarin android application

Tags: android, xamarin, service

I have created 2 Xamarin android applications.  One application hosts an android service.  The other is a client application.  It is suppose to only start the service calling StartForegroundService.  It does not need to communicate with the service or get a response, so there is no need to use a bound service.

Currently this is just 2 test applications.  I have created the same application in Java and Android Studio.  They work just fine.  The client starts the service in the second application, no problems.

The Xamarin flavours do not work.  I am 90% sure the issue is with the Xamarin Android service, because my Xamarin client application, can start the service in the Java Android Studio version of the service.  Further testing also revealed the Java android studio client could not start the Xamarin android service either.

So for some reason, when I write a service (as identically as possible) in Xamarin, it can't be started by other applications.  But if I write it in Java and use Android studio, it works just fine.

Here is the manifest of my service application.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.androidservicet3" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="androidservicet3.AUTOSETTLE" />
  <permission android:name="androidservicet3.AUTOSETTLE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="AndroidServiceT3.AutoSettleService" android:permission="androidservicet3.AUTOSETTLE">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidservicet3.autosettle" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:name="crc645835191c6c6c2b11.MainActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.androidservicet3.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.companyname.androidservicet3.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the manifest of my client:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.settleclient" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
  <uses-permission android:name="androidservicet3.AUTOSETTLE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.b2ps.servicetest2.autosettle" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:name="crc641e54c039a041334a.MainActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.settleclient.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.companyname.settleclient.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the service:

```
    [Service( Exported = true, Name = "AndroidServiceT3.AutoSettleService", Permission = "androidservicet3.AUTOSETTLE" )]
[IntentFilter( new String[] { "androidservicet3.autosettle" } )]
public class AutoSettleService : Android.App.Service
{
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    // Unique Identification Number for the Notification.
    // We use it on Notification start, and to cancel it.
    private int NOTIFICATION = Resource.String.autosettle_started;

    private System.Threading.Timer serviceRun = null;

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
    // RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private IBinder mBinder;

    /**
     * Class for clients to access.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with
     * IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder : Android.OS.Binder
    {
        private AutoSettleService mService;

        public LocalBinder( AutoSettleService service ) { mService = service; }

        AutoSettleService GetService() { return mService; }
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        mBinder = new LocalBinder( this );
        mNM = ( NotificationManager )GetSystemService( Context.NotificationService );
        // mLogger = Logger.getDefault();

        // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
        // ShowNotification();
    }

    public override void OnStart( Intent intent, int startId )
    {
        base.OnStart( intent, startId );
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", "AUTOSETTLESERVICE: OnStart" );
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand( Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId )
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent );

        try
        {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( this, typeof( MainActivity ) );
            notificationIntent.SetAction( AutoSettleConst.AUTOSETTLESERVICE_ACTION );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity( this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable );

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder( this, AutoSettleConst.APP_CHANNEL_TXN_ID )
                    .SetContentTitle( "Auto-Settle" )
                    .SetContentText( "Running Auto-Settle" )
                    .SetSmallIcon( Resource.Drawable.AppLogo)
                    .SetContentIntent( pendingIntent )
                    .SetTicker( "ticker text" )
                    .SetOngoing( true )
                    .Build();
            // .SetForegroundServiceBehavior( ( int )NotificationForegroundService.Immediate )

            // Notification ID cannot be 0.
            StartForeground( AutoSettleConst.AUTOSETTLE_NOTIFICATION, notification );

            serviceRun = new System.Threading.Timer( ServiceTimer, null, 0, 1000 );
            // autoSettleTask = Task.Run( () => {
            //     Console.WriteLine( "Do auto settle" );
            //     AutoSettleTask();
            // } );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", e.ToString() );
        }
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Cancel the persistent notification.
        mNM.Cancel( NOTIFICATION );

        // Tell the user we stopped.
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", "Service destroyed" );
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind( Intent intent )
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", "AUTOSETTLESERVICE: binding" );
        return mBinder;
    }

    public override bool OnUnbind( Intent intent )
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", "AUTOSETTLESERVICE: unbinding" );
        return base.OnUnbind( intent );
    }

    private int _serviceCounter = 0;
    private void ServiceTimer( object state )
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", $"AUTOSETTLESERVICE: ServiceTimer: {_serviceCounter++}" );
        if( _serviceCounter >= 15 )
        {
            serviceRun.Dispose();
            serviceRun = null;
            this.StopSelf();
            Android.Util.Log.Debug( "AUTOSETTLESERVICE", $"AUTOSETTLESERVICE: Stopping service" );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void ShowNotification()
    {
        // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
        string text = GetText( Resource.String.autosettle_started );

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        // PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        //         new Intent(this, LocalServiceActivities.Controller.class), 0);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( this, typeof( MainActivity ) );
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity( this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable );

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder( this )
                .SetSmallIcon( Resource.Drawable.AppLogo )  // the status icon
                .SetTicker( text )  // the status text
                                    // .SetWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )  // the time stamp
                .SetContentTitle( GetText( Resource.String.autosettle_label ) )  // the label of the entry
                .SetContentText( text )  // the contents of the entry
                .SetContentIntent( contentIntent )  // The intent to send when the entry is clicked
                .Build();

        // Send the notification.
        mNM.Notify( NOTIFICATION, notification );
    }
}


public class AutoSettleConst
{

    public const string AUTOSETTLE_ACTION = "com.somecompany.terminalservice.autosettlets";
    public const string AUTOSETTLENOTIFY_ACTION = "com.somecompany.terminalservice.autosettlenotify";
    public const string AUTOSETTLESERVICE_ACTION = "com.somecompany.terminalservice.autosettleservice";
    public const string AUTOSETTLE_TIMEOUT_ACTION = "com.somecompany.terminalservice.autosettletimeout";


    // Android notification constants
    public const string APP_CHANNEL_TXN = "Transaction ChannelXX";
    public const string APP_CHANNEL_TXN_ID = "com.somecompany.terminalservice.txn";
    public const string APP_CHANNEL_TXN_DESCRIPTION = "Transaction notifications";

    public const int AUTOSETTLE_NOTIFICATION = 1001;

}
```

Comment: I have now tried to start the service using binding.  Same problem is occurring.  The service does not start.  So for some reason the service is unaccessible from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this in your manifest in the client App, as it targets API30+:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.companyname.androidservicet3" />
</queries>
```

Then you should be able to start the service in the other app with:

```
var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(
    "com.companyname.androidservicet3",
    "AndroidServiceT3.AutoSettleService"));
Application.Context.StartService(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I tried it.  It did not resolve my issue.  Furthermore, I do not have a section like that in the manifests of my Java Android Studio versions, and they work.  Also, as mentioned, I did not have that in my Xamarin client and it could successfully start the service in application created in Java and Android Studio.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was very simple.  It was the ComponentName added to the intent to start the service.  Really the cause was just how Xamarin/Visual Studio create default projects vs how Android Studio created projects.  And then where you pt the service in your path.

The package name in the ComponentName must be the android package name defined in the Manifest element of the Manifest.XML.  I was using the namespace name of the service.  In Java/Android Studio, these just happened to be the same.  In Xamarin/Visual Studio these were different.

Manifest of service application:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.androidservicet3" android:installLocation="auto">
```

Launch service from client:

```
    Intent autoSettleIntent = new Intent();
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName( "com.companyname.androidservicet3", "com.companyname.androidservicet3.AutoSettleService" );
autoSettleIntent.SetComponent( cn );
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.AppContext.StartForegroundService( autoSettleIntent );
```

My error code has a different Package Name and Service class name before I fixed it.  Unfortunaetely, I didn't post the original error code.  Anyhow make sure package: equals the Manifest package name, and the class = fully qualified service class name.